# Exclude certain semantic from dynamic versioning

Tags: gradle, dependencies, semantic-versioning

I want to use dynamic versioning and lock the dependencies. Is there a way to do sth like:
`1.+.X`, where X means that I want to exclude the patches from dynamic dependency resolution, but I want to keep track of the minor releases? Sth like::

1. 1.1.1 is used in the `gradle.lockfile`
2. 1.2.1 is released
3. 1.2.2 is released
4. I do `./gradlew dependencies --write-locks`
5. `gradle.lockfile` is updated and 1.2.1 is used

Comment: What do you mean by "keep track of the minor releases"? 
Do you want to use 1.2.1 because the gradle lockfile previously had a 1 in the patch part of the version when it was at version 1.1.1?
In my mind it makes sense to just exclude the .X part and write the version as "1.+". But that will resolve to 1.2.2 when you write locks again. Which isn't what you're asking for here. Is it?

Comment: It isn't, when `1.2.2` is released I don't want this version. I want only minors